# How to get batch-inserts with back references to work?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Here's my Android problem that I've spend hours on already:

I am inserting objects in table CARS, followed by objects in table DRIVERS. I need DRIVERS's foreign-key to be set correctly to reference the just inserted row in CARS. Also, if row in DRIVERS cannot be saved, CARS should not be saved, as well. (transactiomn-semantics)

I am using the ContentProvider-approach.

I understand I should use a batch insert and `withValueBackReference` for this task.

Example code:

```
// (populate carData obejct..)

ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> opList = new
                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ContentValues carv = new ContentValues();
carv.put(Car.CAR_MAKE, carData.make);
carv.put(Car.CAR_MODEL, carData.model);
carv.put(BaseColumns._ID, 0); // this HAS to be here or withBackValues doesn't work

opList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Car.CONTENT_URI).withValues(carv).build());

ContentValues driverv = new ContentValues();
driverv.put(Driver.DRIVER_NAME, carData.driverName);
driverv.put(Driver.DRIVER_CAR_FK, 0); // THIS should set the ID of the car above!

opList.add(ContentProviderOperation. newInsert(Driver.CONTENT_URI).withValues(driverv)
          .withValueBackReference(Driver.DRIVER_CAR_FK, 0).build());

//... applyBatch etc.
```

If I leave out `carv.put(BaseColumns._ID, 0)` it doesn't work. If I leave it in, I have to set the value `AUTO INCREMENT` would have assigned. (Driver._ID is set to be the primary key.)

So my question is,

how to to have the `CARS` row set its own _ID, and reference this id in the second insert of the batch, when I insert the `DRIVER`?

Help is very appreciated, the documentation isn't very clear..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late to help, but you seem to have the right idea. From your example your db naming scheme is a little confusing. You should not need `carv.put(BaseColumns._ID, 0);` because the database should be creating this value for you. You also don't need to put `driverv.put(Driver.DRIVER_CAR_FK, 0);` though it won't hurt - according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.Builder.html#withValueBackReference(java.lang.String,%20int)) value back references take precedence. If there are still issues then it is probably because of the way the foreign keys in your database are set up.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> opList = new
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ContentValues carv = new ContentValues();
carv.put(Car.CAR_MAKE, carData.make);
carv.put(Car.CAR_MODEL, carData.model);
opList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Car.CONTENT_URI).withValues(carv).build());

ContentValues driverv = new ContentValues();
driverv.put(Driver.DRIVER_NAME, carData.driverName);

opList.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Driver.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValues(driverv)
          .withValueBackReference(Driver.DRIVER_CAR_FK, 0).build());
```